# How do I display a JSON status message in a view for a controller action success or failure in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, response

I send certain data from a view to my controller. The controller action checks to see if the user has enough money, and if so, allows them to buy a tool of a certain price.
Otherwise, it doesnt update their tool.
Either way, I want to send a JSON response back to the view, to display.

How do I display these messages?

Here is my controller:

```
# Updates dollars and tool id when a user goes shopping in 'store'...
  def update_tool

    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @tool = Tool.find(params[:toolId])
    price = @tool.price

    # subtract tool price from users dollars
    if @user.dollars <= price

      respond_to do |format|
        msg = { :status => "error", :message => "You do not have enough money!", :html => "<b>NO MONEY!</b>" }
        format.json  { render :json => msg }
      end

    else

      @user.dollars = @user.dollars - price

      # re-assign users tool_id reference ID
      @user.tool_id = @tool.id

      #store to database
      @user.save

      #sends a confirmation back to store
      respond_to do |format|
        msg = { :status => "success", :message => "You purchased a tool!", :html => "..." }
        format.json  { render :json => msg }
      end
    end
  end
```

I want to take these status responses and use them to trigger events in my view,
something like this:

```
success: function(){
      window.alert(':message');
    },
error: function(){
      window.alert(':message');
    }
```

I'm just uncertain how to access the content of the json response message.

---

UPDATE:

Heres my AJAX request, with my success or failure functions:

```
function buyTool() {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': '<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s %>'
    },
    url: '<%= update_tool_path %>',
    dataType: "JSON",
    async: true,
    data: {
      'user_id' : <%= @user.id %>,
      'toolId' : toolId
    },
    success: function(){
      window.alert(":json");
    },
    error: function(){
      window.alert(":json");
    }
  });


};
```

Its not working though-- My alert windows just actually displays the text ":json".

Do I need to pass the anon error: function that data?

Comment: You need to do Ajax call in your frontend Javascript code. Here is something you can take a look: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: Close, in your callback function, you can do it like this :
success: function( json ) { alert(json.message)}

Comment: Using -- success: function( json ) { alert(json.message)} -- I am still getting back 'undefined'.

Comment: You can check your Ajax call from developer tool if you are using Chrome. Verify the response is correct. Then you can debug your response in the callback like this: success: function(json){console.log(json);alert(json.message)}

Comment: When I check my json reponse in the console, I dont see my error message text. It does get the correct success: or error: status though.

Comment: I was reloading the view so that the newly purchased tool would be reflected, using -- location.reload(true); -- in my buy function. This was screwing it up.

Answer (score 1):

My preference for this is to use flashes that are triggered by ajax. To do this use the following.

Add the following to your `ApplicationController.rb`

```
  after_filter :flash_to_headers
  #....
  private 

  def flash_to_headers
    return unless request.xhr?
    response.headers['X-Message'] = flash_message
    response.headers["X-Message-Type"] = flash_type.to_s

    flash.discard # don't want the flash to appear when you reload page
  end

  def flash_message
    [:error, :warning, :notice, :success].each do |type|
      return flash[type] unless flash[type].blank?
    end
  end

  def flash_type
    [:error, :warning, :notice, :success].each do |type|
      return type unless flash[type].blank?
    end
  end
```

And then add a flashes.js.coffee file with the following (This uses bootstrap styled flashes so just change the classes to something with your own styling)

```
show_ajax_message = (msg, type) ->
  if (type == "error")
    $("#flash-message").html "<div id='flash-#{type}' class='alert alert-danger'>#{msg}</div>"
  else if (type == "success")
    $("#flash-message").html "<div id='flash-#{type}' class='alert alert-success'>#{msg}</div>"
  else if (type == "notice")
    $("#flash-message").html "<div id='flash-#{type}' class='alert alert-info'>#{msg}</div>"  
  else if (type == "warning")
    $("#flash-message").html "<div id='flash-#{type}' class='alert alert-warning'>#{msg}</div>"
  $("#flash-#{type}").delay(5000).slideUp 'slow'

$(document).ajaxComplete (event, request) ->
  msg = request.getResponseHeader("X-Message")
  type = request.getResponseHeader("X-Message-Type")
  show_ajax_message msg, type
```

Finally add somewhere for the flashes to render

```
# views/shared/_flashes.html.erb
<!-- Id is used for ajax flashes -->
<div id="flash-message">
  <% if flash[:notice] %>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
      <%= flash[:notice] %>
    </div>
  <% elsif flash[:error] %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <%= flash[:error] %>
    </div>
  <% elsif flash[:alert] %>
    <div class="alert alert-info">
      <%= flash[:alert] %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% flash.discard %>
</div>
```

and render it from your layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= render 'shared/flashes' %>
```

After this you can trigger flash messages as you would normally in rails and they will appear.